# without approval for more US military assistance from Congress in the coming weeks

Tags: sentence-structure

> Ukrainian cities will be vulnerable to Russian missile attacks this winter **without** approval for more US military assistance from Congress in the coming weeks, White House officials have warned.

Source: https://www.telegraph.co.uk/world-news/2023/11/15/ukraine-vulnerable-russian-attacks-white-house/

---

Is the object of "**without**" "approval for more US military assistance from Congress in the coming weeks" or is it "approval for more US military assistance from Congress"?
In other words, is "in the coming weeks" a part of the object of "**without**"?

Comment: I would understand "in the coming weeks" to be a prep-phrase modifying "approval" and thus part of the object of "without".  It can be relocated: "without approval in the coming weeks for more ..."

Comment: without approval for more US military assistance from Congress in the coming weeks=if there is no more US military assistance from Congress in the coming weeks//It's all one idea. "in the coming weeks" is just a prepositional phrase functioning as temporal adverbial. Yes, it can be moved as TimR says but with commas around it: without, in the coming weeks, approval for etc.

Comment: @TimR Could "**in the coming week**" be moved before "approval" as Lambie says?

Comment: @Englishgood   If the sentence were rewritten as follows, with the  word "Unless" and the verb "approves" instead of the noun "approval", the phrase "in the coming weeks" could occupy the position Lambie has chosen for it: "Unless, in the coming weeks, Congress approves more military assistance for Ukraine, that country's cities will be vulnerable to Russian missile attacks this winter." Even so, I would still recommend  that the phrase be placed after "approves", the verb it would modify: "Unless Congress approves in the coming weeks more military aid for Ukraine, ...".

Comment: @TimR In 'the noun phrase "two people waiting outside" has “people” as head **with** the gerund-participial clause “waiting outside” **as modifier of the head**', is "**as modifier of the head**" a part of the object of "**with**"?

Comment: @Englishgood .I would not consider "as modifier of the head" to be integral to the object of the prepositional phrase headed by "with". I take  "as modifier of the head" to be a further assertion about the role played by "waiting outside". It's like saying "Tom went to the dance *with Jane* **as his date**"  where "as his date" gives further info about Jane's role.  However, at a higher level, "with Jane as his date" is a semantic unit in that sentence.

Comment: @TimR Thank you. I will not consider "as modifier of the head" to be part of the object of the prepositional phrase headed by "with".

Comment: @Englishgood   Don't take my word for it though. You might want to ask on linguistics.stackexchange.com -- since the answer to such questions about clause structure depends on your analytical framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase "*approval for more US military assistance*" is the object of 'without. You could end the sentence here and it still make sense.

The words "*from Congress*" is a propositional phrase stating the origin of the object - where it has to come from.

Likewise, "*in the coming weeks*" is a qualifying phrase indicating the required *timing* of the approval.